# Formatting time for HH:mm in groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm having an awful time trying to format `2014-06-02T15:00:00.000-0700` as `HH:mm`

I have tried `def arrivalTimeFormatted = arrivalTime.format("HH:mm")` with no luck.

Comment: Is `2014-06-02T15:00:00.000-0700` a String or a Date or something else? If it's a Date that will work, if it's a String it will give you `"HH:mm"`

Comment: Its supposed to be a `time` variable. How can I test for the data type? I am writing this in the SmartThings IDE so I'm not totally sure www.smartthings.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Date.parse( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", '2014-06-02T15:00:00.000-0700' )
    .format( 'HH:mm' )
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: this looked like it was going to work, but my input of `2014-06-03T10:00:00.000-0700` returned `17:00`. My code `def arrivalTimeFormatted = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", arrivalTime).format('HH:mm')` It looks like its screwing with the 7 hour timezone offset

Comment: ok fixed it.. i added `def tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone('PST')` to `def arrivalTimeFormatted = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", arrivalTime).format('HH:mm', tz)`